# finding all occurance of a particular field value inside object tree

Tags: javascript, arrays, hash

I am trying to print the values of all the occurence of a field "term".. with the program Ive written it only returns the first occurence.. Is it possible to get whole occurence?

http://jsfiddle.net/AQ5WK/

```
var data = {
"_index": "test",
"_type": "news",
"_source": {
    "partnerName": "propertyFile 9",
    "relatedSources": "null",
    "entityCount": "50",
    "Categories": {
        "Types": {
            "Events": [{
                "count": 1,
                "term": "Time",
                "Time": [{
                    "term": "Dec 9",
                    "Dec_9": [{
                        "count": 1,
                        "term": "2012"
                    }]
                    }]
                }, {
                "count": 4,
                "term": "News",
                "News": [{
                    "term": "Germany",
                    "Germany": [{
                        "count": 1,
                        "term": "Election"
                    }],
                    "currency": "Euro (EUR)"
                }, {
                    "term": "Egypt",
                    "Egypt": [{
                        "count": 1,
                        "term": "Revolution"
                    }]
                    }]
                }]
            }
    }
}};

var findDeepKey = function(obj, key){
var results = [];
if (typeof obj !== 'object') return null;
for (var k in obj) {
    if (k === key) return obj[k];
}
for (var k in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[k] === 'object') {
        if (obj[k].length) {
            for (var i = 0, il = obj[k].length; i < il; i++) {
                results.push(findDeepKey(obj[k][i], key));
            }
        } else {
            for (var kk in obj[k]) {
                if (kk === key) return obj[k][kk];
                results.push(findDeepKey(obj[k][kk], key));
            }
        }
    }
}
for (var i = 0, il = results.length; i < il; i++) {
    if (results[i] !== null) 
            return results[i];
}};

alert(findDeepKey(data, 'term'));
```

​

Comment: The key Im trying to find out is term... Time is the first occurence of key "term"

Comment: Yes, sorry... I just noticed... however... if you move var results[] before your recursive function and you do an alert(results.length), you'll see your reults array has 6 members...

Comment: some say its good to post jsfiddle link.. I will post the relevant code

Comment: @T.J.Crowder code added to question... sorry for the inconvinience

Comment: @user1371896: FYI, what you have there isn't JSON, it's a JavaScript object initializer; what you're searching isn't JSON, it's an in-memory object tree. JSON is a non-code, textual data interchange format which is *based on* JavaScript's object initializers, but without some of their features. If you were to "search through JSON", it would be a string operation. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks.. bt what am I doing wrong in my pgm?? it wont return anything other than first occurence

Comment: put an alert right before all of your return statements... you'll see all 6 "terms"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to print the values of all the occurence of a field "term"

Anywhere it exists at any level of the object tree? That's a recursive-descent search: [Live example](http://jsbin.com/obehog) | [source](http://jsbin.com/obehog/edit)

```
function findProps(name, data, results) {
  var key, value;

  // If we weren't given a results array, create one
  if (Object.prototype.toString.call(results) !== "[object Array]") {
    results = [];
  }

  // Is it an object (including an array)?
  if (typeof data === "object") {
    // Yes, loop through its properties
    for (key in data) {
      // Does it have an "own" property with this name?
      // (I assume you only want "own" properties, not
      // properties inherited from the prototype chain).
      if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        // Yes, get the value
        value = data[key];

        // Is this our property?
        if (key === name) {
          // Remember it
          results.push(value);
        }

        // Recurse into the value?
        if (typeof value === "object") {
          // Yes
          findProps(name, value, results);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // All done
  return results;
}

var terms = findProps("term", data);
display("Found 'term' " + terms.length +
        " time(s): " + terms.join(", "));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot and thanks a for explaining everything in detail.